# CSS + HTML division layering with z-index goes wrong

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have a problem with divs in HTML/CSS with the z-index. This is the HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
        <div class="banner-lijnen">
            <div class="banner-vervaging">
                <div class="banner-images">
                    <img src="images/home/banner/home1.jpg" width="1185px" height="465px" />
                </div>

            </div>

    </div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
 div {position:relative; 
 }
        .banner {height: 465px;
             background: #262262;
             width:100%;
             z-index: 3;}

    .banner-container {height:465px;
                      width:1185px;
                        float: none;
                        margin:0px auto;
    }
    .banner-vervaging {
        background-image: url('images/home/banner/overgang.png');
        width:1185px;
        float:none;
        margin: 0px auto;
        margin-top: -20px !important;
        height: 465px;
        background-size: contain;
    }
    .banner-lijnen {
        width: 100%;
        height: 425px;
        border-bottom: 20px solid rgba(144, 142, 173, 0.5);
        border-top: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) solid 20px;
    }
    .banner-images {
        width:1185px;
        height: 465px;
        z-index: -2;}
```

The thing is, .banner-lijnen must be on top, under that one .banner-vervaging, under that one .banner-images and it's content. But the only thing I can manage to do is .banner-images under everything and .banner-vervaging on top of the rest. (http://www.bgc-testomgeving.nl/wal) is the link to the website i'm talking about.

Greetings,

Bruce

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: I've updated my post :)

Comment: What about taking off the margin-top:-20px;

Comment: the margin-top: -20px is there so that the .banner-images and .banner-vervaging is also under the 20px border of .banner-lijnen.

Comment: `z-index` doesn't take effect unless the element has a position value of something **other** than `static`. Try `position:relative`.

Comment: On div if have already position: relative, so everything is relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested elements cannot be z-indexed above their parents. See

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

To solve your problem, make the `banner-images` div a sibling (same level as) the `banner-lijnen` div:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner-images">
        <img src="images/home/banner/home1.jpg" width="1185px" height="465px" />
    </div>
    <div class="banner-lijnen">
        <div class="banner-vervaging">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your css, make all divs `position:relative` except banner-images, which should be `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;width:100%;`, or something like that. *Then* you can use z-index to position the divs on top of one another.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1osa1njd/)

There is also no problem in making them all siblings with `position:absolute`, then using z-index to position them as desired:

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner-images">
        <img src="images/home/banner/home1.jpg" width="1185px" height="465px" />
    </div>
    <div class="banner-lijnen"></div>
    <div class="banner-vervaging"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey gibberish, I fixed it with the help of the first peace of your answer. position: absolute wasn't needed but images and lijnen as siblings fixed nearly all problems. Just a margin-top: -465 on the .banner-images and it was done. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible for an element to appear behind its parent, with the exception of elements with a negative z-index (which appear behind all other elements). Your `.banner` element has a z-index of 3 .. i'm guessing because you want that element to appear on top of all others. But `banner-lijnen` and `banner-vervaging` are nested elements with no z-index specified, so they wont appear behind `banner` (their parent).

So, two options: 1) make all the divs at the same level; 2) specify negative z-index for both `banner-lijnen` and `banner-vervaging`.

Comment: Hi Don, Tried your answer but it didn't work out. The answer below yours did actually work. .banner-images and .banner-lijnen are now sibblings and that + a margin-top: -465px on .banner-images nailed it. Anyway, thanks for your help!